# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::via()

Tags: php, laravel, email, notifications

I've added the following to my `App\User` model:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $message = (new MailMessage)
        ->from(config('myapp.email'), config('myapp.title'))
        ->subject('Reset Password')
        ->view('emails.password_reset', compact('token'));

    $this->notify($message);
}
```

This is causing the following error:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::via()`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Notifications`, not `Emails`. This is why it requires the `via` method.

If you simply want to send an email, use the `Mail` facade instead.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with this.